# Switching back to read-only filesystem

Tags: mount, ubuntu-touch, filesystem

I am using the Nexus 4 with UbuntuTouch installed.

I switched to a writable filesystem by this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

and it worked perfectly.

How to switch back correctly to read-only filesystem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where `rw` is read-write, `ro` is read-only:

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /
```

See [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount.8).